# Submit a form on close tab/window event

Tags: javascript, forms, events, drupal-form-submission

I'm wondering if there is a way to submit the contents of a form when the user closes a tab/window. I've looked into the `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` events and think maybe this is the road to go down. I've tried

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { 
  document.getElementById("my-form").submit();
};
```

but that doesn't work. Is there a way I can get this to work in the way I am describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use JQuery, give this a try:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
   $("#id-of-submit-button").click();
});
```